# Image Competition, Finishes end of February 2023

Tags: discussion, photo-competition

Inspired by the Winter/Summer Bash, I would like to suggest a competition into which you can post your photos or self made artwork.
The theme this time is Hats.

You can post up to 3 photos or images of the same hat, (or different photos of an artwork of a hat) per post and up to three posts.
The competition starts immediately and will run till there are 10 entries and/or the end of January.

There will be two different winners, one is the one who has the most votes by the time we close the competition, based on how busy it is there might be a time announced for the last votes, the other is picked by me but I am open to suggestions, we call that one the virtual prize.

All entries have to be suitable for work.
The artwork has to be made by you photos can be taken by you or a named travel companion, the hat does not need to be made by you.
Like the Winter/Summer bash, we accept a very wide range of hats, but we do prefer it to be worn on the head.

Please do not downvote, leave a comment instead if you do not like an entry, downvotes will not be counted.

This competition will be resolved at the end of February, I fear we will not make it to ten posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: hat (with head) before a city map]

My traditional 'you are here' hat photo as new(ish) mod on Travel Stack Exchange, which is one of the few hats on me photos I own.
Photo taken September 2018, Desenzano del Garda, Italy, by me.

Comment: This is the post with the most votes at the closing of the competition, so the winner.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

My hat which is now 12 years old, has become a significant part of my trekking gear. It has been with me through scorching heat and torrential rains. It has been with me during my hikes around low-laying sea forts as well as at altitudes as high as 20000 feet.
Almost all of my mountaineering pictures has me with this hat on!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Location: see photo

Date/time: November 1st, 2022, at sunrise (what a wonderful moment to be there!)

No doubt the hat of my brother on the left was better suited for the temperatures, but I couldn't resist wearing the official [Stack Exchange moderator cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299484/295232) ...

Answer (score 2):

[image: Blue felt hat with yellow braided band]
My then new hat, with an older braided turks hat knot style band, which had been on my previous blue hat before getting moved here.
This photo was well before covid but I do not remember how many years.
While I did not make the hat, I did make the braid and it consist of one length of yellow string, going round in an over two, under two sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Now I'm not really a hat person. Where I live it really doesn't get cold enough for hats. That said, I do occasionally wear my West Lothian Dippers hat when it's a bit cold in the water. Gloves will also be needed for the next couple of months as well, until the water temp gets back up above 7 or 8C.

[image]

Comment: Not cold enough for a hat? Does that exist? I wear one year round if I feel like it. But gloves but no wetsuit, that is special. The hat is a nice extra. You win the virtual prize this time.

Comment: @Willeke - fingers and toes do have a habit of getting cold. So neoprene gloves and boots really help. And thank you for the prize :-)